# Why Ajax load more and Isotope not working together?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-isotope

I am trying to use Isotope in my custom Loadmore js. Its working fine without Isotope but when i am adding Isotope there its not working and appended content overlapping.

**Ajax Code**

```
  $load_posts_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var request_next_link =
      pagination_next_url.split(/page/)[0] +
      'page/' +
      pagination_next_page_number +
      '/';

    $.ajax({
      url: request_next_link,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $load_posts_button.text(decoding_translation_chars(pagination_loading_text));
        $load_posts_button.addClass('c-btn--loading');
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      var posts = $('.infinite-post', data);
      $('.infinite-scroll').append(posts); 

      $load_posts_button.text(decoding_translation_chars(pagination_more_posts_text));
      $load_posts_button.removeClass('c-btn--loading');
      pagination_next_page_number++;
      // If you are on the last pagination page, hide the load more button
      if (pagination_next_page_number > pagination_available_pages_number) {
        $load_posts_button.addClass('c-btn--disabled').attr('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  });
```

I tried with the following code to activate isotope there,

```
$.ajax({
  url: request_next_link,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $load_posts_button.text(decoding_translation_chars(pagination_loading_text));
    $load_posts_button.addClass('c-btn--loading');
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  var posts = $('.infinite-post', data);    

  var $posts = $('.grid').isotope({
    // main isotope options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 2,
    }
    })

  $('.infinite-scroll').append(posts);
```

But its not working. Isotop css not injecting in my loaded content.  So its not working with my custom load more code.

[image]

Comment: If your dynamically added content contains images you will need to wait for them to load before calling `isotope()` otherwise it will see see the contents size before the image is loaded and its size reflows the dimensions

Comment: Unfortunately, masonry not working with that code when I trigger load more button. It does not inject CSS code from isotope in HTML.. Please check the attached image in that question, so you will understand the problem.

Comment: Note you need to make the isotope call after appending the new posts otherwise it doesnt know to reflow the new elements as they wont exist in the dom yet

Comment: Or add the posts through the [appended()](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended) isotope instance method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery to append elements to your pre-existing Isotope instance, you can use their API's [`addItems` method](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#additems). This is assuming that you have instantiated your Isotope somewhere in the code and stored a reference to it, i.e.:

```
// Assuming that you have instantiated Isotope elsewhere
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope(...);
```

And then you can simply do:

1. [`$grid.isotope('addItems', $posts);`](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#additems) to add all new incoming posts from your AJAX request into your grid, and then
2. [`$grid.isotope('layout');`](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout) to force a relayout

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: request_next_link,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $load_posts_button.text(decoding_translation_chars(pagination_loading_text));
    $load_posts_button.addClass('c-btn--loading');
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  var posts = $('.infinite-post', data);    

  // Add all new posts to your grid
  $grid.isotope('addItems', posts);

  // Force grid to relayout
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```